# Xamarin.Android Material Button SetMinHeight programmatically?

Tags: xamarin.android

I'm trying to create a Material Button programmatically in Xamarin.Android and attaching this to a TableRow which is in turn attached to a Table. In OnCreate, I SetContentView before calling the CreateButtons() function below. When I use SetMinHeight() inside the function, the button shows but the min height doesn't appear to work. However, when this code is added to the click event and the button is pressed, it updates the button correctly.

The function that loads with the Activity:

```
public void CreateButtons()
{
    var tableLayout = FindViewById<TableLayout>(Resource.Id.tableLayout1);
    
    TableRow.LayoutParams buttonParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(
        0,
        TableRow.LayoutParams.WrapContent,
        1.0f
    );

    buttonParams.SetMargins(3, 3, 3, 3);

    TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
    tr.LayoutParameters = new TableRow.LayoutParams(
        TableRow.LayoutParams.WrapContent,
        TableRow.LayoutParams.WrapContent
    );

    MaterialButton button = new MaterialButton(this);
    button.Text = "Test Button";
    button.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;
    button.IconSize = 158;
    button.Icon = GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.goodsin);
    button.IconGravity = 16;
    button.Click += Button_Click;
    button.LayoutParameters = buttonParams;
    button.SetMinHeight(126);
    tr.AddView(button);
    tableLayout.AddView(tr);
}
```

The button after the function has generated it, cutting the text off:
[image]

The code inside the button click event:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var button = (MaterialButton)sender;
    button.SetMinHeight(126);
}
```

The button after the click event has completed, now showing the correct size and text:
[image]

Comment: I tried to repeat your problem but I failed. And I even couldn't set the min Height in the clicked event. But you can try to set the button.SetMinHeight(126); button.SetMinimumHeight(126); The MinimumHeight is for the Button and the MinHeight usually is for TextView.

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT it doesn't seem to matter if I use SetMinimumHeight or SetMinHeight, the problem is the same. When it is called in a standard function, it doesn't load correctly. However, when it's called within the button click, it works.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Today I had done a new demo and used your code without the icon. But the code works correctly no matter if it is in the click event or in the function.